# SPO 2013 - Renaming Document Libraries does not affect the tree view?

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharepoint-online, office-365, rename

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

In our document center site we have a tree view enabled in our site settings, so that all the Site Contents (Document Libraries) are shown in the left side of the page (a bit like the view in Windows File Explorer). When we create of delete a Document Library from the Site Contents, it affects the tree view so that the items appear/disappear from there too.

Now when we try to rename a Document Library in the Site Conents by going to the settings of that library, the name does change in the "Site Contents" list but in our tree view at the left side of the page it will still show the old name.

What is wrong? How to fix this? Is there another way to rename Document Libraries so that the renaming would affect the tree view too?

Thank you!

Comment: How have you renamed the the document library ?

Comment: The problem has solved by itself it seems, but still I will answer to you. The renaming was done by going into Site Contents, clicking the three dots of my Document Library and clicking the option to change the name and description.

Comment: Maybe it was a caching issue because the navigation is normally cached.

Comment: @StefanBauer I think you are right. Anyways thank you a lot for answering and trying to help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by itself during the last night it seems. Today I tried the renaming again and it worked perfectly. So if someone runs into a similar problem, try waiting a day before putting in hours to figure out what's wrong. :-)

I just wanted to add this information as an answer so that the question gets more "Closed" -feeling to it and someone else might save some work by reading this.

**EDIT/NOTES:** Like Stefan said, it might have been caused by a caching issue.